# How to join all rows from one table against each row in another table

Tags: excel

I am trying to find a way to efficiently join two tables of data together that don't have any common data in excel.

for example:

| name |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |

| number |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

I then want the final product to be:

| name | number |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

With Power Query: assuming your first table is *Table1* and your second *Table2*, create the following query:

```
let
  Source             = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Table1"]}[Content],
  #"Changed Type"    = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"name", type text}}),
  #"Added Custom"    = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Table2),
  #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"number"}, {"number"})
in
  #"Expanded Custom"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365 you can also use this formula:

```
=LET(
colA,A2:A6,
colB,B2:B5,
cntRows1,COUNTA(colA),
cntRows2,COUNTA(colB),
maxRows,MAX(cntRows1,cntRows2),
MAKEARRAY(cntRows1*cntRows2,2,LAMBDA(r,c,
       CHOOSE(IF(ISODD(c),1,2),
              INDEX(colA,ROUNDUP(r/maxRows,0)),
              INDEX(colB,ROUNDUP(r/maxRows,0))
             ))))
```

You have to adjust the ranges for `colA` and `colB` to your needs.

[image]